# Установка cpan EV модуля

Tags: perl

Привет.Пытаюсь установить модуль cpan EV

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install EV"
```

ломается на ошибке untar EV-4.15.tar и не может скомпилировать. Предлагает установить вручную. Врунчую ставиться нормально. и при последующих вызовах команды выше пишет что уже такой модуль успешно установлен.

Но проблема в том, что другие программы, использующие данную библиотку, не видят ее. Может нужно прописать путь к ней в переменную path?

```
cpan[1]> test EV CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'Database was generated on Tue, 11 Jun 2013 05:07:37 GMTRunning test for module 'EV'CPAN: Data::Dumper loaded ok (v2.124)'YAML' not installed, falling back to Data::Dumper and Storable to read prefs     '/root/.cpan/prefs'Running make for M/ML/MLEHMANN/EV-4.15.tar.gzCPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.47)CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.037)Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/EV-4.15.tar.gz okScanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizesUse of uninitialized value $newdir in substitution (s///) at /usr/lib64/perl5/Cwd.pm    line 502.Use of uninitialized value $newdir in chdir at /usr/lib64/perl5/Cwd.pm line 510.Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at /usr/lib64/perl5/Cwd.pm line 510.Use of uninitialized value $newdir in pattern match (m//) at /usr/lib64/perl5/Cwd.pm line 525.Use of uninitialized value $newdir in split at /usr/lib64/perl5/Cwd.pm line 531.............................................................................DONEUncompressed /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/EV-4.15.tar.gz successfullyUsing Tar:/bin/tar xvf "EV-4.15.tar":Couldn't untar EV-4.15.tarCPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)Package seems to come without Makefile.PL.  (The test -f "/root/.cpan/build/MLEHMANN-fDun4t/Makefile.PL" returned false.)  Writing one on our own (setting NAME to EV)  Had problems unarchiving. Please build manuallyRunning make test  Make had some problems, won't testFailed during this command: MLEHMANN/EV-4.15.tar.gz                      : unwrapped NO -- untar failed
```

Comment: нужен лог, что конкретно за ошибка

Comment: выложил лог

Answer (score 2):

А что мешает поставить из репозитория?

```
sudo aptitude install libev-perl
```

Comment: Отсутствие знаний. Спасибо за совет!)

Answer (score 2):

```
...Using Tar:/bin/tar xvf "EV-4.15.tar":Couldn't untar EV-4.15.tar...
```

говорит, что в

```
cpan[1]> o conf
```

нужно поискать

```
 tar                [/bin/tar]
```

и поменять его на то, что скажет

```
# which tar
```

в обычном шелле. Либо это точ такая же проблема, но с gzip (потому как там файл gz всё-таки), решать также.

Comment: наверное всё-таки с gzip проблема более вероятна.    # which gzip    cpan[1]> o conf gzip ...    cpan[2]> o conf commit

Comment: Спасибо, но решил уже другим путем